# key :xxx not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :xxx is not loaded> in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I generated two models `Prefecture` and `Shop`.
`Shop` belongs to `Prefecture`.

I get errors:

```
key :prefecture_name not found in:
# Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :prefecture is not loaded>
```

I wrote following code.

Prefecture.ex

```
defmodule Sample.Prefecture do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "prefectures" do
    field :prefecture_name, :string

    has_many :shop, Sample.Shop

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(prefecture, attrs) do
    prefecture
    |> cast(attrs, [:prefecture_name])
    |> validate_required([:prefecture_name])
  end
end
```

Shop.ex

```
defmodule Sample.Shop do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "shops" do
    field :address, :string
    field :phone_no, :string
    field :store_name, :string
    belongs_to :prefecture, Sample.Prefecture

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(shop, attrs) do
    shop
    |> cast(attrs, [:store_name, :address, :phone_no, :prefecture_id])
    |> validate_required([:store_name, :address, :phone_no])
  end
end
```

It seems to be OK. But the error is happened.

```
key :prefecture_name not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :prefecture is not loaded>
```

What I want to make is to get prefecture_name.

What do I need for this code?

Comment: are you trying to access `shop.perfecture.perfecture_name`?

Comment: Yes. I would like to get it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I got #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564255/why-i-got-ecto-association-notloaded)

Comment: Yes. However I totally forget how to do it. I thought it caused version difference.

Comment: could you update more details in your question? which line of code make this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I should have written following.

```
   Repo.all(Shop) |> Repo.preload(:prefecture)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to access relations you have to [preload](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3) them. This happens because when you get a specific schema from database, the nested relations are not pulled, you have to explicitly do that.

In your case suppose you have value `shop` witch represents a record from your database:

```
shop_preloaded = shop
|> Repo.preload(:prefecture_name)
```

Comment: Where I should write?

Comment: 'def list_shops do
    shop_preloaded =
      Repo.all(Shop)
      |> Repo.preload(Prefecture, :prefecture_name)
  end'

Comment: It does not work. '(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3
'

Comment: try `shop_preloaded = Repo.all(Shop) |> Repo.preload(:prefecture_name)`

Comment: I still have error. (ArgumentError) schema Sample.Shop does not have association :prefecture_name